# Grouping one column using agg & join but only on unique values

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have this cunning piece of code that i'm using on the following dataset

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({
    'contact_email': ['info@info.com', 'info@info.com', 'info@info.com'], 
    'interest': ['Math', 'Science', 'Science']
})
    print(df)
    interest contact_email
0   Math    info@info.com
1   Science info@info.com
2   Science info@info.com

df = df.groupby('Contact_Email').agg({'interest' : ' '.join}).reset_index()
print(df)

        contact_email   AOI
0   info@info.com   Math Science Science
```

this is so close to what I wanted, but i need to only return unique interest. (I have users/customers entering the same form, with the same values almost 10 times!)

also, as a nice to have does anyone know how to remove the 0,1,2,3 index.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unique.html) for remove duplicates:

```
df = (df.groupby('contact_email')
        .agg({'interest' : lambda x: ' '.join(x.unique())})
        .reset_index())
print(df)
   contact_email      interest
0  info@info.com  Math Science
```

Or `set`s, but order of values should be changed:

```
df = df.groupby('contact_email').agg({'interest' : lambda x: ' '.join(set(x))}).reset_index()
print(df)
   contact_email      interest
0  info@info.com  Math Science
```

Or [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df = (df.drop_duplicates(subset=['contact_email','interest'])
       .groupby('contact_email')
       .agg({'interest' : ' '.join})
       .reset_index())
print(df)
   contact_email      interest
0  info@info.com  Math Science
```

Comment: @Datanovice - You are welcome! But if need the best performance I guess last solution should be fastest (depends of data)

Comment: I only have 3 thousand records and we only get 4-8k users entering our forms per month so this is perfect :)

Answer (score 4):

Since you have only one function, you can use `groupby` + `apply` and utilize `set`:

```
res = df.groupby('contact_email')['interest']\
        .apply(set).apply(' '.join)\
        .reset_index()

print(res)

   contact_email      interest
0  info@info.com  Math Science
```