# pandas Generate sorted list of unique values per ID

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd data = [['Adam',12,'M','A',12,15], 
        ['Adam',12,'M','B',13,15],
        ['Adam',12,'M','C',14,14],
        ['Mini',12,'F','A',10,14],
        ['Mini',12,'F','D',14,15],
        ['Mini',12,'F','C',13,16],
       ] df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name','Age','Gender','Subject','minmark','maxmark']
```

The requirement is to generate a new column 'SubjectList' which is the sorted list of Subject opted by each student.

**output Expected:**

```
Name    Age Gender SbjectList
Adam    12  M      A,B,C
Mini    12  F      A,C,D
```

Comment: let's see what you've tried so far? easier to zero in on where you're having issues

Comment: Can use [np.unique](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) which will handle both sorting and unique as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68582895/15497888) and then `join` like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51378865/15497888): `df.groupby(['Name', 'Age', 'Gender']).agg(SbjectList=('Subject', lambda x: ','.join(np.unique(x))))`